# Calculating rho values for a lemniscate graph

Tags: plot, graph, scilab, calculus

I am trying to graph a lemniscate in polar coordinates on scilab. Which formula is
`rho^2=a^2*cos(2*theta)`.

The thing is that calculating the square root of certain values will return an imaginary number as the value would be negative.

```
clear
close
clc
clf
a=3;
theta=[0:((1*%pi)/180):((359*%pi)/180)];
rr=(a*a)*cos(2*theta);
rho=sqrt(rr);
polarplot(theta,rho,2);
```

Anyways, the program breaks itself when the negative `rr` values are reached since the square root is not properly defined for them.

All I need is the code to ignore those points and plot the others.

I don't know if this is understandable, but I hope someone do and can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may ignore (e.g. filter out) those points, but there is an even easier solution: use only the real part of your result vector for the plot with `real`

```
polarplot(theta,real(rho),2);
```

You may also assigh it to a new variable if want to use it later:

```
rhoreal=real(rho);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked flawlessly.